# React Edit Table

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, edit, populate

I am trying to edit a single row but edit all rows, also still trying to add a drop down that will populate some rows, any advice or info will be appreciated.

Here is the code I am  using,

```
<TableBody>
    {item.userBankAccount.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <TableRow hover key={index}>
                {!currentlyEditing ? (
                    <TextField
                        label="bankName"
                        name="bankName"
                        onChange={(e) => this.onChangeUserBankAccount(e, index)}
                        type="text"
                        value={item.bankName || ''}
                    />
                ) : (
                    <TableCell>{item.bankName}</TableCell>
                )}

                {!currentlyEditing ? (
                    <TextField
                        label="BankAddress"
                        name="bankAddress"
                        onChange={(e) => this.onChangeUserBankAccount(e, index)}
                        type="text"
                        value={item.bankAddress || ''}
                    />
                ) : (
                    <TableCell>{item.bankAddress}</TableCell>
                )}

                {!currentlyEditing ? (
                    <TextField
                        label="bankSwift"
                        name="bankSwift"
                        onChange={(e) => this.onChangeUserBankAccount(e, index)}
                        type="text"
                        value={item.bankSwift || ''}
                    />
                ) : (
                    <TableCell>{item.bankSwift}</TableCell>
                )}
            </TableRow>
        );
    })}
</TableBody>
```

[image: it T]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is here,

In each line of `TableRow` you have

```
{!currentlyEditing ? (
```

this is same for all `TableRow`. so, if one gets `currentlyEditing = true` then all of them becomes editable.

#### Solution:

Just take the `state` of `currentlyEditing` in the `TableRow`
So, Each an every of `TableRow` gets their own `currentlyEditing` state,
AND, thus others in the mean time will not be editable

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback but could you maby give an example ,still new at react

Comment: i will have to create stuff to make the example, insted can you give me any sandbox, that will be whole lot faster

Comment: when you say just use the state in the table row ,what do you mean by that, only create one {!currentlyEditing ? } inside table row ,bit confused

Comment: @ChrisJnrPotgieter i meant that your `TableRow` is getting their state data from the main table component, that causing the problem

Comment: So, just place that state in in `TableRow` component instead of the main table compoennt

Comment: So something like this ?   {!currentlyEditing ?   (<TableRow hover key={index}> <TextField> ) : (<TableCell)} Just trying to understand

Comment: @ChrisJnrPotgieter No, Simple Words, Take `currentlyEditing` *state*   in your `TableRow`  component, AND do ` {!currentlyEditing ? ` this kinda stuff in the `TableRow`

Comment: Why dont you simply give me a sandbox, Understanding things Abstractly can be hard sometimes. SO simply give me any sandbox or enough example, if you want the answer

Comment: Ok created a sandbox added all my code ,backend not connect to get apis for the data ,  hopefully this is better https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-brattain-8qm72?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hey, its not working, Just cut the code for one an only `table` & `rows` nothing else..

Comment: The err is `ModuleNotFoundError
Could not find module in path: '../../components/LoginView/services/auth.service' relative to '/src/App.js'`

Comment: Created new sandbox that viewable ,no data but when you want to add edit mode everything edits , sorry for the hassel https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-zhukovsky-4nvf9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: there is no data ,dont know if you have an api to just replace the ones in the code, feeling like a noob :0

Comment: ok, enough i will take care of it, i can help you that much, no worry...

Comment: @ChrisJnrPotgieter moving to chat room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217643/discussion-between-axuser264-and-chrisjnr-potgieter).